# CarrierWave full url for default image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rails-api

I am using [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for image uploads on a [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) application which in turn is consumed by a `backbone.js` client app. I notice that when there is no default image available it returns `/assets/default.png`. It in turn has to be `http://dev-server:3000/assets/default.png`. Here are my configuration settings:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.asset_host = "http://dev-server:3000"
end

# Image Uploader
....

def default_url
  "/assets/default.png"
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edit (updated answer)]

Updating my answer to setup `asset_host` in rails config.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  .
  .
  config.asset_host = 'http://dev-server:3000'
end
```

Then you can use `asset_url` method or `image_url` method of the helper. Since this is an image, I would recommend placing the image in `app/assets/images` folder and use `image_url`.

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url("default.png")
```

This will give you the following URL:

```
http://dev-server:3000/images/default.png
```

You can try it in the console.

[Old Answer]

Looking at [Carrierwave Documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url), it seems like your `default_url` method should look like this (Carrierwave does not automatically perpend asset_host to the default url):

```
def default_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default.png")
end
```

I am assuming that `asset_host` is setup properly in your Rails configuration. If not, please do so.

Comment: As you see in my question, I have setup the `config.asset_host = "http://dev-server:3000"`. And I also tried including `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default.png")` in the `default_url` method and it still doesn't give the full url path.

Comment: You have `asset_host` setup in Carrierwave config. I meant to add it to Rails config (outside Carriwave block). See [Rails Configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) for reference. I am editing my answer based on this.

Comment: @Sam I'm using the asset pipeline. And do you have any comment on the answer that I wrote?

Comment: What I gave is cleaner. That's it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Rails 5 API and Carrierwave too.

A lucky guess got it working for me.

I have a file inside `app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb`.

The `asset_host` configuration is set inside this file (at least it works for me):

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ...

  def asset_host
    return "http://localhost:3000"
  end

end
```

Hope this works for anyone else in the future having this problem.

Comment: This one worked for me with Rails 5 api mode. Adding config.asset_host in development.rb didnt work

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend some of your ideas:

I: Put Host in your environment z.B. development.rb

```
config.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

II: Create file in config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :file
  config.asset_host = ActionController::Base.asset_host
end
```

III: Edit your uploader to:

```
def default_url
    "#{asset_host}/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
```

IV: **RESTART** your server

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by looking into the code of `carrierwave`. This is what I ended up doing:

```
  def default_url
    "#{asset_host}#{ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default.png")}"
  end
```

Also make sure that you include the `asset_host` configuration in your respective environment files.