# How to get uploaded file path from Carrierwave in jquery in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using Carrierwave on Rails to handle file upload.

It's working well and I want to make new feature on my app to display uploaded file with jquery (kind of preview uploaded file)

Therefore, I have to pass uploaded file url to the script
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it.

**File upload model**

```
class OrderFile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    validates :file, presence: true
    mount_uploader :file, StLuploaderUploader
end
```

**Form to upload new file**

```
  <%= form_for OrderFile.new, html: { multipart: true }, :url => url_for(:controller => 'order_files', :action => 'create') do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :file, class: "form-control" %>
  <% end %>
```

**jquery File Upload call**

```
jQuery(function() {
    return $('#new_order_file').fileupload({
        autoUpload: true,
        add: function(e, data) {
            var file, types;
            types = /(\.|\/)(png|jpg|)$/i;
            file = data.files[0];
            if (types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)) {
                data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file));
                $('.CO-file_upload_progress').append(data.context);
                data.submit();
            } else {
                return alert("Not supporting");
            }
        },
        progress: function(e, data) {
            var progress;
            if (data.context) {
                progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                return data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            }
        },
        done: function(e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
                prepare_file(file); // passing file to the function
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Function to preview file**

```
function prepare_file(file) {
    loaded(file.url, "model-preview"); // I need an absolute path to the uploaded file to be passed here - file.url is not working
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897832/carrierwave-full-url-for-default-image

Comment: That wont help. I do not need default path, just the path to file, which was already uploaded